# Scrolling to div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

This code scroll too low! I need it to scroll less for about 40px. 
How do I implement this in below example ?

```
 <script>
       $(".scroll").click(function(event){
               event.preventDefault();
               //calculate destination place
               var dest=0;
               if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
                    dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
               }else{
                    dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
               }
               //go to destination
               $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 500,'swing');
           });
    </script>
```

I will be grateful for your help :*

Comment: Can you show the HTML you're trying to apply it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's suitable to you, you can just add `'-40'` to your `dest` variable:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest-40}, 500,'swing');
```

Another way is to scroll to element which is located higher than element you scrolling to. Depends on your design.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to scroll down the anchor #here, by clicking on a link with the class .scroll

```
jQuery('.scroll').click(function() {
jQuery('html, body').animate({ 'scrollTop': jQuery('#here').offset().top }, 'fast');
return false;
});
```